# Get web page icon

Tags: android, web-applications

I am developing a web based app. The app is going to use quite a lot of different icons, and I was wondering if there where anyway of loading it from the web. I have noticed that almost every webpage has a small icon like the New York Times icon next to the home button:

[image]

How do I get this icon with only useing the url?

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon), and you can get it the same way the browser does: request the image over HTTP. As the Wikipedia article describes, the URL is typically sent in a `<link>` element in the `<head>`.

For example, if you view the source of this page, this tells us the URL:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
```

Comment: Put in some effort. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+download+image+http

Answer (score 1):

its normally in the root of the site /favicon.ico

however on stack its at /img/favicon.ico,

you could run search through the heads of the websites for the link tag with the rel attribute of icon

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
```

Here is how stack overflow link to their own icon